# PJSUA2: Error creating SDP answer: SRTP crypto attribute required

Tags: android, webrtc, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm trying to use the latest version of pjsip for android
https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android.

And got an error for incoming call:

```
Error creating SDP answer: SRTP crypto attribute required (PJMEDIA_SRTP_ESDPREQCRYPTO) [status=220228]
inv0x78653290a8  .Sending Response msg 406/INVITE/cseq=47488686 (tdta0x78bfbcf0a8)
```

Account configuration for use srtp

```
    SrtpOpt opt = new SrtpOpt();
    IntVector optVector = new IntVector();
    optVector.add(pjmedia_srtp_keying_method.PJMEDIA_SRTP_KEYING_DTLS_SRTP);
    optVector.add(pjmedia_srtp_keying_method.PJMEDIA_SRTP_KEYING_SDES);
    opt.setKeyings(optVector);

    accCfg.getMediaConfig().setSrtpOpt(opt);

    accCfg.getMediaConfig().setSrtpUse(pjmedia_srtp_use.PJMEDIA_SRTP_OPTIONAL);
    accCfg.getMediaConfig().setRtcpMuxEnabled(true);
    accCfg.getMediaConfig().setSrtpSecureSignaling(0);
```

Looks like that missed a=crypto: attribute in sdp, but I don't understand how to include it.

However, old version that we used before - works and I don't understand the reason.

And I think if error in creating SDP answer then maybe problem is in incoming sdp.
Is it client or server problem?

Please, help me resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a server problem.
Works well after upgrade server and add a=crypto attribute into SDP.